# How can I replace missing data with a specific value

Tags: r

I have a column indicating the outcome of patients, however it has many NAs. This column has multiple 'character' options (e.g. 'Alive, discharged with supplemental oxygen', 'Deceased', etc.), however I use an index to dichotomize it so those variables largely don't matter. My issue is that I need to change the NAs into one of the variables in this column ('Outcome'). It can be any of the values except for 'Deceased' including a new one if that works. I'm trying to apply this change across the entire data set as I will then use the new dichotomized across many calculations.

```
cleanset <- Data1 %>% 
  drop_na(BMI) %>% 
  filter(!complete.cases(.))
```

The above represents the first of the code I run to clean up the set. I then would like to follow it with the mutation/transformation of the NAs for the 'Outcome' variable.

```
mutate(cleanset$Outcome = replace_na(cleanset$Outcome, "Alive, discharged with supplemental oxygen"))
```

The above is my failed attempt at achieving this, so I would appreciate any input on how I can successfully mutate the NAs for this variable to give them a specific value.

Comment: Does `cleanset %>%
  mutate(Outcome = replace_na(Outcome, "Alive, discharged with supplemental oxygen"))` works?

Comment: It might also be good to take a look at some beginner tutorials on using dplyr: functions like `mutate` generally operate on a data frame, not vectors, and expect arguments to be passed as bare column names. Such as `mutate(cleanset, Outcome = ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 df%>%
    mutate(outcome_1=case_when(outcome = is.na(outcome) ~"Alive, discharged with supplemental oxygen", TRUE ~ octcome))
```

In this code, I assumed that the outcome column is the column where there is `NA`
so I created another column which is `outcome_1` and replace all `NA` in the outcome column with "Alive, discharged with supplemental oxygen" in the `outcome_1`

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: What's the advantage of using `case_when` over `ifelse` if you only have a single condition? It's much longer, introduces unusual syntax and a base function would suffice. `tidyr::replace_na` is even shorter

Comment: have you been able to resolve it?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward with either `replace_na(outcome, "Alive, discharged with supplemental oxygen")` or `ifelse(is.na(outcome), "Alive, discharged with supplemental oxygen", outcome)`, but this is also a question that has a lot of duplicates on SO, including the one I flagged it as

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still having issues. I tried @user16087142 's approach first with the relevant syntax ` mutate(Outcome_1=case_when(cleanset$Outcome = is.na(cleanset$Outcome) ~"Alive, discharged home on supplemental oxygen.", TRUE ~ cleanset$Outcome))`
but I receive the following error: unexpected '=' in "mutate(Outcome_1=case_when(cleanset$Outcome ="

I then tried @camille 's method both with replace_ na (which runs, but the console just says 'character(0)' and doesn't result in any change) & then with if_else but that also fails to result in any changes

Comment: Just for further clarification, when trying @camille 's method, I wrote it up as follows:

`replace_na(cleanset$Outcome, "Alive, discharged home on supplemental oxygen.")`

`ifelse(is.na(cleanset$Outcome), "Alive, discharged home on supplemental oxygen.", cleanset$Outcome)`

when is make a table  `table(cleanset$outcome)` the result shows the same values for each category as before.

if anyone has any other suggestions I'd truly appreciate it
Thank you!

Comment: @ClinicalPursuits45 I think there's probably still problems with how you're using dplyr functions and/or whether you're actually assigning anything back to your data frame; see my comment on your question

Comment: @ClinicalPursuits45 can you share a sample dataset ??

Comment: So I'm quite confused because it looks like some of these mutate functions are actually working when I input into console:
`cleanset %>% 
  select(Outcome) %>% 
  mutate(outcomes = replace_na(Outcome, "A"))`
The above code results in the console outputting a 'Outcome' & modified 'outcomes' column with the 'outcomes' column having had its NAs replaced by the value 'A'. That's exactly what I need; however, if I then try to view the 'outcomes' vector it doesn't appear?! I've truly never seen this before